# Asp.net Mvc 6 get user claims immediately after log in

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

In a Asp.net Mvc 6 website I customized the out-of-the-box `AccountController` so that I add a custom Claim before calling `userManager.CreateAsync()`, both when registering

- with a local account (email/password), in the `Register()` method of the controller
- with an external provider (google/facebook), in the `ExternalLoginConfirmation()` of the controller

Now what I'd like to do is, immediately after the user logs in, both

- in the `Login()` method after calling `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` and
- in the `ExternalLoginCallback()` method after calling `signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync()`

...to retrieve that claim, ideally without hitting the DB to get the User.

I noticed that if I look at User directly after sign-in, the Claims collection is empty. However, if I look at it in a subsequent controller action the Claims collection is populated and has my custom claim in it.

The question is, why isn't the Claims populated immediately after sign-in (I guess the sign-in code doesn't refresh the CurrentPrincipal?) and is there another place to check directly after sign-in to get the claims without hitting the DB?

Comment: I am able to repro what you are seeing, may be this is by design...try posting this question at http://github.com/aspnet/identity/issues

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement your own ApplicationUserStore and fill whatever properties of the user (or entity which is used as identity entity) you need.